# Can several logic systems coexist physically in the same world?

Tags: logic, philosophy-of-science, metaphysics, physics

In mathematics, each logic system is associated with an abstract model. In physics, similarly, each logic system is associated with a physical model that models a part of the universe, but I don't hear about models where two logic systems exist simultaneously, so I was thinking the physical world can only have one logic system at a time. Does that make any sense, and what was said about this?

Comment: Is logic a technical term in physics different from the usual sense? Because unless the word means something different, it is not the case that each logic system is associated with a physical model that models a part of the universe. Quite the contrary, the whole point of logic in the usual sense is to abstract from any particular way that the world could be.

Comment: Logics are associated with physical models not because the exist physically, but because they are bookkeeping devices for making use of those models, like database interfaces. You do not hear about models with two different logics simply because it is impractical, not because it is impossible. But, either way, it has little to do with what exists in the world.

Answer (score 1):

> Can several logic systems coexist physically in the same world?

A logic system is a system of formal logic and it is an empirical and trivial fact that there are several systems of formal logic proposed in the literature, all really irrelevant.

Logic itself is something else. The academic world tend to confuse "logic" and "formal logic", but logic is properly speaking a cognitive faculty, and neither a formal discipline nor a formal system.

Given this, it is for now impossible to answer your question.

The only logic we know of is our own and we don't understand how it really works. It is conceivable that some intelligent species elsewhere in our galaxy or in some the billions of galaxies which may exist in the universe has a different, perhaps very different logic, from our own. My guess is that the logic that we have is an effective compromise ensuring the survival of the species. It seems effective for enough people to survive, prosper and reproduce to ensure the survival of humanity itself. It seems in this respect a good compromise between the complexity of our logic, its efficiency in the terrestrial environment, the viable size of the human brain, its "biological" speed, and probably many other factors such as the energy required by the brain etc.

A brain relying on very different biological principles could conceivably have a more complex logic.

It is of course imaginable that we could develop a more effective logic and implement it on computers, although I suspect that current computers are not powerful enough to equal the human brain.

However, it is imaginable but I don't think it is really conceivable. And I don't even believe that this is really possible in practice.

Our logic is in fact quite simple and effective. All we really need is to understand how it really works so as to be able to implement it on computers to get rid of the limitations of the human brain. In other words, I don't believe that different logics from our own could exist. Any difference with other intelligent species will be in terms of the efficiency of the brain.

Our logic is best understood as the engine behind our intelligence, and I don't think we could conceive a better logic using our own logic. I also don't believe that nature could possible produce a more complex logic. What we see is probably all that there is in this respect.